# Class using the iter protocol

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.6

I have a small class that creates a building.  I am wanting to learn more about **iter**.  The following works:

```
class Building(object):
    def __init__(self, floors):
        self._floors = [None] * floors

    def __setitem__(self, floor_number, data):
        self._floors[floor_number] = data

    def __getitem__(self, floor_number):
        return self._floors[floor_number]

    def __iter__(self):
        for floor_number in self._floors:
            yield self._floors[floor_number]


building1 = Building(9)  # Construct a building with 9 floors
building1[0] = 'Reception'
building1[1] = 'ABC Corp'
building1[2] = 'DEF Inc'
building1[3] = 'Apple'
building1[4] = 'Cisco'
building1[5] = 'Microsoft'
building1[6] = 'Dell'
building1[7] = 'EMC'
building1[8] = 'HPE'

'''
for floor in building1:
    print(building1[floor])
'''

print(building1[6])

Dell
```

But if I un-comment out the for loop I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    for floor in building1:
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 13, in __iter__
    yield self._floors[floor_number]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I understand that list indices have to be integers. What I am not getting is why this for loop is violating that restriction.

What I am wanting to do is exercise the **iter** protocol and print out every floor in the building, not just a specific one.

Comment: As a side note, for an iterable class that just "forwards" its iteration like this, you almost always want `__iter__` to be one of `return iter(something)` or `yield from something`. If neither of those is what you want, it's a good sign that you _aren't_ just writing a forwarding iterable and you need to have a second thought at how your thing fits into the protocol.

Comment: As another side note: You're creating something that acts like a mutable sequence. If you inherit `collections.abc.MutableSequence`, it will let you write just a handful of methods, and fills in all the rest of the methods that your type needs to act like a list. It can still be instructive to build your own versions those methods—but now you can switch them on and off for interactive development and testing, which can be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood what a `for` loop does; you don't have *indices*, you have your *actual values in the list*. Just yield those:

```
for contents in self._floors:
    yield contents
```

You need to do the same in your outer loop:

```
for contents in building1:
    print(contents)
```

Python `for` loops are [*Foreach loops*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), you iterate over the values, not an index.

Instead of looping, your `__iter__` method could just return an iterator for the list, effectively delegating to the list iterator that `iter()` produces for you:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._floors)
```